# How to reinstate most recent commit in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I've searched the docs of Mercurial and still am confused. What I'm wanting to do is just reinstate the last commit I made i.e. I want my project to go back to being exactly the same as it was when I made the last commit. I see hg revert, rollback, etc. and still am not understanding which is correct for this situation. Which should I use?

Comment: FYI: depending on your end goal and if you had pushed the changeset, you could just `hg update -r <previous commit>` and carry on developing from there. You would then have a local dangling head, but history is littered with the fractured forms of paths not taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hg rollback` command is used to undo the last action that modified Mercurial's internal store, usually a pull or commit. So, if you want to undo your last commit `hg rollback` will work.

But it sounds like you want to undo all your uncommitted changes. You have two options. The `hg revert --all` command will undo all uncommitted changes. Each changed file is saved/backed-up with a `.orig` extension before being reverted.

If you don't need to preserve your changes in `.orig` files, run `hg update -C`. This clears out *all* uncomitted changes, without preserving anything.

Comment: Sigh. I love downvotes without advice on how to make it better.

Comment: Maybe, for recommending rollback? Which marked in help "(DANGEROUS) (DEPRECATED)"?! Because undo (any) commit anyway - `hg backout`

Comment: I use rollback all the time. It is not dangerous. When I mess up a commit, like making it on the wrong branch, rollback saves the day. It doesn't change anything in your working directory, just Mercurial's internal state.

Comment: I don't like backout because it creates a new commit. If I haven't pushed my change, I prefer rollback.

Answer (score 0):

If you have commited changesets and wish to remove them, I like the strip extension, [strip extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StripExtension). With it, you can remove explicit changesets from your history.

However, strip is an unforgiving command, i.e. if you get it wrong there is no retrieval unless you have a backup of the repo. You might prefer the prune command which comes with the [evolve extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EvolveExtension). Using prune, you can mark changesets as obsolete and they will no longer normally be visible in logs or tortoise. [You can make them visible by adding --hidden on an hg log command line, or in tortoise by enabling the Filter toolbar (from the view menu) and selecting 'Show/Hide hidden changesets'.]